# How can I handle errors in picocli?

Tags: java, kotlin, picocli

I try to implement my own CLI and want to use picocli for parsing my commands' arguments. That's why I don't want picocli to write in console at all. So I created class `MyCommand` with some option and parameters annotations. Now I want to be able to do something like this:

```
val myCommand = CommandLine.populateCommand(MyCommand(), args)
myCommand.execute();
val output = myCommand.getOutput();
val errors: List<String> = myCommand.getErrors();
```

There is no problems with the first three lines, but I am not sure how to deal with the fourth. Now `populateCommand` just throws all exceptions, and catching them is not an option, because thrown exception will stop my pipeline computations. Picocli documentation suggests to use parser lenient mode for exceptions to be stored in `ParseResult`, but it means I have to use `commandLine.parseWithHandlers` method that is hard to use for my needs.
Am I missing something? Maybe I sill can use `populateCommand` and have exception stored in some place?
Here is stacktrace for one of exceptions that `populateCommand` throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" picocli.CommandLine$MissingParameterException: Missing required parameter for option '-A' (<afterContext>)
    at picocli.CommandLine$Interpreter.assertNoMissingParameters(CommandLine.java:8059)
    at picocli.CommandLine$Interpreter.applyOption(CommandLine.java:7534)
    at picocli.CommandLine$Interpreter.processStandaloneOption(CommandLine.java:7446)
    at picocli.CommandLine$Interpreter.processArguments(CommandLine.java:7355)
    at picocli.CommandLine$Interpreter.parse(CommandLine.java:7226)
    at picocli.CommandLine$Interpreter.parse(CommandLine.java:7116)
    at picocli.CommandLine.parse(CommandLine.java:824)
    at picocli.CommandLine.populateCommand(CommandLine.java:777)
```

Comment: You need to specify what kind of exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: @ScubaSteve For what? What exactly do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest, that you specify the exceptions being thrown. A stack trace, for example.

Comment: @ScubaSteve I have no idea how can it help, but here you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ignoring parsing errors is unusual, but can be useful when creating
>   your own *interactive* CLI console, as opposed to a single command. My answer assumes this is what you have in mind.

One idea is to use the `parseArgs` method instead of the `populateCommand` method. This method returns a [`ParseResult`](https://picocli.info/apidocs/picocli/CommandLine.ParseResult.html) from which you can obtain the errors that picocli encountered during parsing, if you’ve configured the parser to be lenient.

For example:

```
val myCommand = MyCommand();
val commandLine = CommandLine(myCommand);

// tell parser to be lenient 
commandLine.getCommandSpec().parser().collectErrors(true);

// parse user input, query result for errors 
val parseResult = commandLine.parseArgs(args); 
val parseErrors: List<Exception> = parseResult.errors();

// ignoring the errors for now...
myCommand.execute();
val output = myCommand.getOutput();
val appErrors: List<String> = myCommand.getErrors();
```

> Note that if there *are* any parsing errors, this means that the user
>   specified invalid input. As a result, your command may not have been
>   correctly initialized. The `execute` method needs to be extra robust
>   to deal with partially initialized options/positional parameters.

TIP: If you are creating your own *interactive* CLI console (as opposed to a single command), you may be interested in [JLine 2](https://github.com/jline/jline2) (requires Java 5 or higher) or [JLine 3](https://github.com/jline/jline3) (requires Java 8 or higher). Picocli provides [picocli-shell-jline2](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-shell-jline2) and [picocli-shell-jline3](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/master/picocli-shell-jline3) modules that have a `PicocliJLineCompleter` that shows context-sensitive completion candidates for picocli commands. (The readme of each module has an example.) Applications that use picocli to define their commands no longer need to hand-code Completers for their commands and options. (An early version of this is used in the [Micronaut CLI](http://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-cli/guide/index.html).)